# Close mobile menu by clicking / tapping outside

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, menu, click

I want to have the option to close a mobile menu by clicking outside of the menu on this site http://test1.wasodesign.com/

I searched StackOverflow and the web, and found this solution

```
<script>$(document).click(function(event) {
    if(!$(event.target).closest('.collapse.in').length) {
        if($('.collapse.in').is(":visible")) {
            $('.collapse').hide();
        }
    }       
})
</script>
```

I applied it, and the issue is that it does close on mobile when clicking outside of the menu but then I cannot reopen the menu afterward.

Is there any reason? How can I resolve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you could try something like:

```
$('body').on("click", ".dropdown-menu", function() {
        $('.dropdown-menu').hide() 
        $('.collapse').hide() 
});
```

With this the menu should open when you click on the button.

```
 $('.dropdown-menu').on("click",function() {
        $('.collapse').show()
        $('.dropdown-menu').show()    
});
```

one of those two should work if not leave a comment.

Comment: the first one close but cannot re-open, the second one doesn't close.